# How to use SlideTransition properly?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am trying to animate an image (or logo) from **center** of the screen to **top** of the screen.

For that, I had a look at `SlideTransition`. It works, but for portrait orientation only. When the device is rotated, the image goes outside of the screen. (maybe I did not understand the `Offset` property correctly!) If I make it work for horizontal, the output of the portrait gets changed.

Let me show you the output:

**Portrait:**

*Before animation*

[image: Before Animation]

*After animation (As wanted)*

[image: After Animation (as wanted)]

**Horizontal:**

*Before animation*

[image: Before Animation]

*After animation **(Problem HERE)***

[image: After Animation (Problem HERE)]

So, as you can see, in horizontal mode, the Logo goes out of the screen.

Here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'SlideTransition Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<Offset> _offsetAnimation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300));

    _offsetAnimation = _controller
        .drive(CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeInOut))
        .drive(Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(0.0, 0.0), end: Offset(0.0, -1.0)));

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('SlideTransition Demo'),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: SlideTransition(
              position: _offsetAnimation,
              child: FlutterLogo(
                size: 200,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          if (_controller.status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
            _controller.reverse();
          } else if (_controller.status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
            _controller.forward();
          }
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SlideTransition` does the fractional translation. And this translation depends on the size of the child of the `SlideTransition` widget.

> Tween(begin: Offset(0.0, 0.0), end: Offset(0.0, -1.0))

This tween translates(moves) the `FlutterLogo` in y-axis for 200(height of the `FlutterLogo` widget)

> Tween(begin: Offset(0.0, 0.0), end: Offset(0.0, -0.5))

This tween translates(moves) the `FlutterLogo` in y-axis for 100(half-height of the `FlutterLogo` widget)

If you just want to animate the image from `center` to `topCenter`, then you can use `AlignTransition`.

**Example**:

```
class FirstPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  FirstPageState createState() => FirstPageState();
}

class FirstPageState extends State<FirstPage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _animationController;
  AlignmentGeometryTween _tween;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
    );
    _tween = AlignmentGeometryTween(
      begin: Alignment.center,
      end: Alignment.topCenter,
    );
  }

  TickerFuture _play() {
    _animationController.reset();
    return _animationController.animateTo(
      1.0,
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Demo")),
        body: AlignTransition(
          alignment: _tween.animate(_animationController),
          child: FlutterLogo(
            size: 200,
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
          onPressed: _play,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Demo:** [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/7401f6d191d05bba9c649968947c04ad)

Answer (score 2):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `OrientationBuilder` and modify `Offset` to what you need

code snippet

```
body: OrientationBuilder(
        builder: (context, orientation) {
          if (orientation == Orientation.portrait) {
            _offsetAnimation = _controller
                .drive(CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeInOut))
                .drive(Tween<Offset>(
                    begin: Offset(0.0, 0.0), end: Offset(0.0, -1.0)));
          } else {
            _offsetAnimation = _controller
                .drive(CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeInOut))
                .drive(Tween<Offset>(
                    begin: Offset(0.0, 0.0), end: Offset(-1.0, 0.0)));
          }
```

working demo

[image]

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'SlideTransition Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<Offset> _offsetAnimation;
  Animation<Offset> _offsetAnimationLandscape;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300));

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('SlideTransition Demo'),
      ),
      body: OrientationBuilder(
        builder: (context, orientation) {
          if (orientation == Orientation.portrait) {
            _offsetAnimation = _controller
                .drive(CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeInOut))
                .drive(Tween<Offset>(
                    begin: Offset(0.0, 0.0), end: Offset(0.0, -1.0)));
          } else {
            _offsetAnimation = _controller
                .drive(CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeInOut))
                .drive(Tween<Offset>(
                    begin: Offset(0.0, 0.0), end: Offset(-1.0, 0.0)));
          }
          return Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: SlideTransition(
                  position: _offsetAnimation,
                  child: FlutterLogo(
                    size: 200,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          if (_controller.status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
            _controller.reverse();
          } else if (_controller.status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
            _controller.forward();
          }
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I like your suggestion. But after looking at @crazy-lazy-cat's answer, I understood what the `SlideTransition` does. Looking at your suggestion, it will still not work, because of different sized devices. For my use case, I just needed something like `AlignTransition`.